# How to parse Google Form data with punctuations

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to analyze Google Form answers. Some questions contain checkbox answers comprised of commas and other punctuations. Here is an example:[image]

I would like to analyze the answers - e.g. which people selected which options, how many people selected each option - beyond the default Google Form summaries. When I open the data in Google Sheets the options selected are concatenated, and because of the multiple punctuations I don't have an easy way to separate out the options.

I thought I could download the Google Form data as a .tsv file, but I can only seem to do that from the Google Sheet where the options are already concatenated and do not generate a useful .tsv file.

How can I download and parse these Google Form answers to analyze?